# sum total in access with same field showing muiltiple times

Tags: ms-access

I am looking to total a column that shows up muiltiple times.
(I have added an example to try to make it clear)

example:

```
name          spent  region          
Panasonic     100    1
Panasonic     100    2
Panasonic     100    3
Sony          100    1
Sony          100    2
```

so the "100" column is a repeating value from the main table and through my sum calculation i want the answer to be 200 meaning that it counts Panasonic once and Sony once, instead i keep getting 500.

If you guys can help me that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use only one record of each name?

This request gives you the sum of every "spent" for each "name"

```
SELECT name, SUM(spent) FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

result:

```
Panasonic    300
Sony         200
```